# Facebook and keyboard animation management

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

Does anyone know how to implement composerBar and keyboard appearing like in Facebook messenger?

After scrolling tableView up, a keyboard appears from bottom smoothly and without any jumps .
In my similar implementation it works like this: after scrolling up, when tableView bottom offset < 0, composerBar's input text field become first responder and keyboard jumps to finger.
Yes, I use `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive`.

How does Facebook implement this smooth animation?

[image: keyboard]

Edit: 
I try to explain how it works in Facebook Messenger, step by step.

I have InputAccessoryView on my viewController (TableViewController). Then I start to scroll TV up (pic 1)

[image]

Then, if bottom inset become more then some value (for example 10) (pic 2), I set firstResponder to inputTextField (pic 3)

[image]
[image]

So, in common case, with 'UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive', keyboard jumps to finger position (pic 4)
[image]

BUT! In Facebook Messenger keyboard drags from bottom with distance equal
to distance traveled by the finger. (pic 5)

[image]

So, facebook messenger somehow control keyboard moving.
Question is: how??

Comment: check this out https://github.com/oseparovic/MessageComposerView

Comment: or you can try this also https://github.com/jmascia/DAKeyboardControl

Comment: @eddwinpaz I tried, as I think, all of this frameworks, but no one can recreate such functionality.

Comment: I know what you mean now.. you mean this https://github.com/jakubknejzlik/GNKeyboardAwareScrollView

Comment: Thanks, but - nope. 
It's just scrollview insets adaptation to open/close keyboard. I also implement such feature in my messenger.
To understand what i mean - just install FB messenger and try to scroll up any dialog TableView.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @simme Nope. After many attempts I just leave it :(

Comment: Did you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Input Accessory View](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/inputAccessoryView)

It is a property of UITextView/UITextField that allows you to set a custom view that will be displayed above system keyboard.

Comment: I use it too, thanks. But main question is - how to drag keyboard from bottom corner without any corrupted animations and jumps to finger position.